# Multiple and not in statements in python

Tags: python

I am trying to read in a file only if several conditions are met. However, the only method I can get working is repetative. Is there a way to simplyfy the conditions into a list and call the list, or a more simplified way of achieving this result?
For example

```
if '$' not in file and '~' not in file and 'diab' not in file:
```

where `file` is the file name and it cannot contain the characters `$,~` nor any elaboration of the word `diab` such as diablo.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
symbols = ["$", "~", "diab"]
if all(symbol not in file for symbol in symbols):
```

Comment: or `not any(symbol in file for ...)`. Depending on context, might be a tad more readable (arguably, of course, but might be worth to show this alternative as well)

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `not` just at the beginning and close everything with parenthesis. Like this. \

```
if not('$' in file and '~' in file and 'diab' in file):
```

Otherwise you can substitute `and` with `&` and `not` with `~`

Comment: How is this less repetitive?

Comment: And no, you can't "substitute `and` with `&` and `not` with `~`". They don't do the same thing

Comment: You avoid using two more nots. But of course the answer above is quite nice too. And of course you can, Python has byte-wise boolean operators since it's interpreter written in C. It should work.

Comment: You reduce the amount of characters in the line, yes, but you didn't solve the repetitiveness problem. What if other symbols are to be excluded as well? You have to add a `and symb in file` for each one, instead of just adding them to a list

Comment: Are the outputs of `print(1 and 3)` and `print(1 & 3)` the same? "It should work" is not good enough, don't suggest answers you are not sure of.

Comment: This is not the equivalent of what the OP wants. Check it on `file = '~'` for example.

Comment: Ok dude, my bad, sorry.